# Configuring external http service in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I have a single page angular app which calls a RESTish service.  How can I configure the base URL for my REST server so that in my services I can use relative URLs?  Also, as I was playing around with the following interceptor I got an error where angular-ui router seemed to be using http to get views so this was affected by the middleware.  Basically I guess I want a second http service to inject into my services that has this middleware, how can I do this?

```
app.config(["$httpProvider", function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('middleware');
}]);

app.factory('middleware', function() {
    return {
        request: function(config) {
            // need more controlling when there is more than 1 domain involved
            config.url = "http://localhost:8080" + config.url;
            return config;
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The `$http` services is very important (and widely used) inside Angular.
You shouldn't alter it like this.

For handling requests to an API, it is best to create a dedicated service (even if it's a wrapper around `$http`).

E.g.:

```
.service('API', function ($http) {
    var baseUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/';
    this.get = function (path, config) {
        return $http.get(baseUrl + path, config);
    }
    ...
});
```

Then you can use your service for all API calls:

```
.controller('someCtrl', function (API) {
    API.get('items').success(function (data) {
        $scope.items = data;
    });
});
```

Comment: Well, I have a service but I want to configure the base url in my app.js and eventually into the app using gulp.

Comment: but I see what you're saying about not altering it like that, so the middleware approach is definitely wrong.  I guess I just need to create a constant in app.js?

Comment: I am not familiar with gulp's workflow and how you can configure the base-URL with it, but if you can define a constant or configure a service in a config block it will definitely work.